# Read selected data with read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]I have an excel file from which I want to read the information below with read_excel:

Column C as the index,

Columns D to AH and Rows [5:15], [18:21], [24:75], [78:80], [84:92], [94:95] as the data the dataframe will contain,

Row 1 as the names of the columns of the dataframe.

1)  How do I read only specific rows?

2)  Although I write use_cols = “D:AH” it still reads all the columns, even the ones after AH

3)  When I set use_col = 2 to get column C as the index I get the error “pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 50 fields in line 2, saw 52”

Here is what I have tried:

```
Timetable = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = "Sheet1", index_col = 2, use_cols = "D:AH")
```

Any help?

Thanx!

Comment: it will be interesting to see your code and the excel file, if you want help

Comment: i dont understand  "Row 1 as the names of the columns of the dataframe."  the row 1 dont begin at the same column as the data? or its your row with 1 in first column?

Comment: I mean the first row to be the names of the columns. I think though that this is done automatically, I don't need to specify anything for this to be done

Comment: Are the row numbers given, or should the loader recognize the data rows? I assume that the columns are given...

Comment: The row numbers are 5-15, 18-21, and 24-80

Answer (score 1):

following your logic, i create a list of rows to selected,  and i use skiprows and rows to select the rows inside the excel file

```
rowstoselect = [[5,15], [18,21], [24,75], [78,80], [84,92], [94,95]]

#read first line to set as name of column
T1 = pd.read_excel("e:\\test.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1", header = None, nrows=1,usecols = "D:AH")
T1 = T1.transpose().astype(str) # convert date to str
T1 = T1[0].values.tolist()
T1.insert(0, "T")          # give a name to index

TimeTable = pd.DataFrame()
for r in rowstoselect:
    T = pd.read_excel("e:\\test.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1", header = None, skiprows=r[0]-1,nrows = r[1] - r[0] + 1, converters={'Date': str}, usecols = "A:AH")
    TimeTable = TimeTable.append(T)

TimeTable.drop(TimeTable.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True) # drop columns A and B

TimeTable.columns = T1   # rename column
TimeTable.set_index('T', inplace=True) # index
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Trying the way you suggested, though, does not set the first row (the one with the dates) as the 1st row of the dataframe, and second, it is still reading all the columns of the file, even the ones after column AH.

Comment: display the dataframe T at first loop to see the result.. it seems you have datas which gives problem... i have tried with a similary excel but with int or str data and no problem. it may be instersting to have a copy of your excel file  ...

Comment: another thing the first row with the date is the row wich begins at column D? its name of column? its format is str or date?

Comment: Yes, that is the first row. Also, I cannot give a copy of the excel file, as it contains a lot of private information in many parts of it. I changed some parts to add a screenshot...

Comment: first type error usecols and not use_cols.  i have fixed in the answer. and you have to select usecols = "A:DH" first if you want to index on column C later..after you drop column unused

Answer (score 0):

Pandas IO tools are great because for simple use cases, they do the right thing and load a whole file in a single (simple) command. The downside is that they may not be versatile enough for too complex use cases. So I would export the Excel sheet to csv and use the Python `csv` module to pre-process the file:

```
def get_data(fd, cur_line, lines, cols):
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    for first, last in row_index:
        while cur_line < first:
            _ = next(fd)
            cur_line += 1
        while cur_line <= last:
            yield next(rd)[cols[0]:cols[1]]
            cur_line += 1

def process(fd, col_index, row_index):
    _ = next(fd)  # skip first line
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    row = next(rd)
    columns = ['ix'] + row[col_index[0]:col_index[1]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(get_data(fd, 3, row_index,
                               (col_index[0]-1, col_index[1])),
                      columns = columns).set_index('ix')
    df.index.name = ''
    return df
```

With your file, I would use:

```
col_index = (3,34)
row_index = ((5,15), (18,21), (24,75), (78,80), (84,92), (94,95))
df = process(open(csv_filename, newline=''), col_index, row_index)
```

The file is processed only once, only relevant lines are processed and only relevant columns are used to feed the dataframe. The only limit is that the ignored lines cannot contain multiline fields. If it is required, you should replace `next(fd)` with `next(rd)` in above functions in order to have the csv module to process the multiline fields.